# Run a command on remote hosts through capistrano from the command line

Tags: ruby, capistrano

Is there way to run a command in capistrano without adding it to a Capfile?

example:

```
cap --eval "run 'du -sh'" --role web
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the (experimental) Capistrano shell.

```
$ cap shell
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this to run a command on the servers.

```
cap ROLES=web invoke COMMAND='du -sh'
```

If you don't even have a cap recipe, you can specify the servers on the command-line:

```
cap -s user=myusername HOSTS=server1.com,server2.com invoke COMMAND='du -sh'
```

To see more command-line options, run `cap -H` and `cap -e invoke`.